# Angular 9: spy await function (unit test)

Tags: angular, unit-testing

Angular 9

I have a function which is `async`, calling another function with await, such like as below.

```
  async hoge() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      this.piyo(i);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      await this.fuga(i);
    }
  }

  fuga(idx: number) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (idx < 5) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    });
  }

  piyo(idx: number) {
    return;
  }
```

And I tried to add unit test for that function `async hoge()`, to check `piyo()` and `fuga()` were called 10 times when executing.

`piyo()`, normal function's test works well ,but `fuga()` didn't; showed error

> Expected spy fuga to have been called 10 times. It was called 1 times.

```
  it("fuga called 10 times from hoge func", () => {
    // spy function which will return Promise
    const spyObj = spyOn(component, "fuga").and.callFake(() => {
      return Promise.resolve();
    });

    component.hoge();

    expect(spyObj).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(10);
  });

  it("piyo called 10 times from hoge func", () => {
    const spyObj = spyOn(component, "piyo");

    component.hoge();

    expect(spyObj).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(10);
  });
```

Considering this case, `async` made this test failed. But I cannot figure out how to modify this test code.
I appreciate it if someone would give me any idea.

It's whole code on the stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unit-tests-uxwzw1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.spec.ts

Thanks you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test does not work, because the code is executed asynchronously (in this case because of the promises).

Angular has [tools to test async code](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/fakeAsync) as `fakeAsync` and `tick`. You can wrap your test with `fakeAsync` and then use `tick` to indicate async execution.

```
it("fuga called 10 times from hoge func", fakeAsync(() => {
    // spy function which will return Promise
    const spyObj = spyOn(component, "fuga").and.callFake(() => {
      return Promise.resolve();
    });

    component.hoge();
    tick();

    expect(spyObj).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(10);
}));
```

Comment: Thanks @code-gorilla I was forgetting the tick() portion of the code. Adding it in, did the job.